# What is clamd's function?

Tags: antivirus, clamav, realtime

I understand that there is currently no real-time AV for Linux, or at least not using ClamAV. So what is `clamd`'s function then? Because that talks about `on-access scanning`, so what is that if not real-time scanning? And why is it running all the time if it's not a real-time addition to ClamAV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned: ClamAV is an on-access virus scanner and not a real-time scanner.

The ClamAV daemon (`clamd`) can be used for scanning incoming files automatically, (E.g. mails) without having to scan them manually with ClamAV.

Excerpt from the Ubuntu community help wiki:

> Lots of programs, especially e-mail servers, can connect to a ClamAV
>   daemon.   This speeds up virus scanning as the program is always in
>   memory.

<sub>[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV#Run_ClamAV_as_a_Daemon)</sub>